# Parsing JSON data into table

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a JSON string like so:

```
{"In Progress":1,"Re-assigned":0,"Completed":0,"Submitted":1,"Reviewed":0,"Assigned":0,"Unassigned":0,"Draft":1,"In Review":0}
```

I want to put it into a simple table formatted like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>State Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

What do I put as the `<tr>` and `<td>` classes?

Comment: I didnt write this but maybe it'll help you: http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/

Comment: must be more data than shown, nothing in data relating to states

Comment: Angularjs does have an ngClass directive, but it has nothing to do with  getting data into your view.  You don't put anything as the classes.

Answer (score 3):

Where your `$scope` looks something like this:

```
$scope.data = { "In Progress":1,"Re-assigned":0,"Completed":0,"Submitted":1 };
```

You need to use a slightly different `for` expression in the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in data">
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    <td>{{ val }}</td>
</tr>
```

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat for examples of the alternative repeat expressions you can use. (in this case you are iterating over keys and values on a single object, not over an array of objects as more common case)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure how that JSON object relates to the table that you're trying to create, but normally what you'd do is use the `ng-repeat` directive to loop through a JSON array like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>State Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="state in states">
      <td>{{ state.StateName }} </td>
      <td>{{ state.Count }} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

where `'states'` in `ng-repeat="state in states"` refers to the JSON object that you're passing in from your `Angular Controller`

Answer (score -1):

To add to Ed B's answer,

You should reformat the JSON into an array that looks like this:

`[
  {'StateName': 'In Progress', 'Count': 1},
  ...
]`

You can make this change in this source of the JSON if you have access or parse it in your Angular code.
Then, you can create a controller with Angular:

`app.controller('StateController', function() {
      this.states = your_json_array;
});`

and add the controller to your HTML with 
`<table ng-controller='StateController as stateCtrl'>`
and `<tr ng-repeat='state in stateCtrl.states'` as well as the bindings (`{{...}}`) shown by Ed B.

Comment: You don't need to reformat the data at all. `ng-repeat` offers syntax for iterating of the keys and values of an object;

Comment: Good to know. I would upvote your answer but I'm not allowed because I'm a newbie.